# Angular 6 fxflex not working with ngif div (if div is shown fxflex is not applied on it)

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material2, angular6

I am trying to use the fxFlex property with ngIf in angular 6, however, it is acting very strangely & not giving the expected output.

[Here is a link to a demo showing the issue on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2gunh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

I expect it to look [like this when it works correctly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-truwtf?file=app/app.component.html)

In that demo, in the first two inputs  I have tried two ways to put the fxflex on the inputs but it acts strangely on both, if I put the fxFlex on the ngIf div, it gives wrong size & spacing:

```
<div *ngIf="true" fxFlex = "20">
      <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput name="dependentRelationship" placeholder="Relationship" [(ngModel)]="data.dependentRelationship"
          required>
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

it works correctly without the ngIf, giving the expected size & spacing:

```
  <mat-form-field fxFlex = "20">
    <input matInput name="dependentRelationship" placeholder="Relationship" [(ngModel)]="data.dependentRelationship"
      required>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Can someone illustrate why fxFlex is not working as expected with the ngIf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ngIf is not the problem here.

The problem comes from your mat-form-field.

With your div, **mat-form-field doesn't get the width:100%**

This code works:

```
<div fxFlex = "20">
   <mat-form-field fxFlex="100">
        <input matInput name="dependentRelationship" placeholder="Relationship" [(ngModel)]="data.dependentRelationship"
          required>
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million, that was the issue, your solution works perfectly!